# Links are apparently not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, wordpress

This website http://multimueblesrd.com/ on the mobile version, has a problem on the section that is with the heading that says: "PRODUCTOS POPULARES", as you may see the links are not working correctly. I click on them but they are not working, please, I need you to tell me possible solutions for this and what could be causing this problem.

Here you can see a screenshot of the exact section that has the click's broken.
https://www.screencast.com/t/lyQNtTHVCW

Thank you!

Comment: Update your quetion and show the related code

Comment: What did you mean @JaromandaX ?

Comment: Ok @scaisEdge I've updated it as you told me to..

Comment: Post the code  too ...not only img ... (is the code  the cause of this ......)

Comment: The problem is that this is a wordpress site, and you can use the developper tools to see the code, and what I want is you to see the mobile  version because the problem is just on that version ... @scaisEdge

Comment: `I want is you to see the mobile version because the problem is just on that version` - so, you don't know how to debug on a mobile, so you want someone to do it for you?

Comment: Zah, obviously I know how to do it, but what I needed is to see what was causing this exact problem and what could be a solution ... I've solved hundreds of problems debugging on a mobile, but this one is really weird for me ...

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think the problem is that you div with class `vc_row wpb_row vc_inner vc_row-fluid` (The one showing Muebles de Bajo Precios) is over the previous div, covering your links

Comment: Wao, Excellent! but now I have the problem that I do not know what to do, because this div is supposed to be under those other divs (taking in consideration the order of the divs on the HTML document) ... Could you help me out with it?

Comment: This is exactly what's wrong. Great catch @berserck.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out how to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

[image]Your problem is that you haven't defined your paths to those pages. Your link to Nosotros works, because it has a defined path. The others are defined as '#', which means nothing has been defined and the link won't work. Use Nosotros as an example to fix the other paths.

[image]

Comment: Well, you didn't get what I was talking about ... Please see the image I posted on the updated question right now ... Thank you!

Comment: I get that your links aren't working. I have no idea what you're displaying in that picture but most of your site doesn't work because you haven't defined the paths.

Comment: I've not defined those paths because I don't want to at this moment ... what I meant was really different of what you got ... :/

Comment: What's the direct link to the page in your picture?

Comment: This is the picture: https://www.screencast.com/t/lyQNtTHVCW  and this is the site:  multimueblesrd.com
But please, see the page like if you were on a smartphone (going trough the web developer tool and activating the mobile view version).

Comment: One of is is not understaning something. These links worked fine for me. Look at the picture I added to my answer about your links that actually don't work.

Comment: Did you check on them using the mobile view on the developers tool ? or if you want you can try getting there with your smartphone ...

Comment: It works fine on my phone (Safari). Doesn't work at all using the iPhone 6s emulator in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes there are some divs that go over other divs even when those divs are supposed to be under them ... A way that I found to fix this problem is just to add: "display: inline-block;" and applying it to the div that is over the others you will be able to take that div and tells the website that it should be on its place so it does not interrupts other divs spaces.

Thank you all for your help!